# How can I implement infinite list with custom views as rows in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6, uiscrollview

I know that it is a common pattern in iOS applications to implement feeds for example. Here is a screenshot from official VK iOS application:
[image]

As you see it is an infinite scrollable list where content (images,text , etc) is displayed in  subviews of different size.

May be there is some ready for use view controller for this? Or I must create it manually - `ScrollView` with subviews which is created dynamically when I scroll it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> an infinite scrollable list where content (images,text , etc) is displayed in subviews

You basically just gave the definition of [`UITableView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451)

Comment: Or `UICollectionView`, but yes...

Comment: @shem correct, even though `UICollectionView` would be an overkill for a simple news feed :)

Comment: But as you see rows in this tables are of differents size and there are margins from each side of it. I have no idea how can I customise simple `UITableView` in such a way...

Comment: Read the guide. And use different cell prototypes

Answer (score 0):

To have different heights your `UITableViewDelegate` should implement the method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` as such :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return <size of your cell according to your data>
}
```